# Pagination Error during export in JasperServer

Tags: pagination, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, jasperserver

When I export a report from Jasper Server into the Excel(Paginated) format. I don't see pagination at the end of each page.

Any suggestions on how to solve this error? Ignore Pagination property of the report is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it happens when we display the data that is actually in the form of a table directly in the detail band rather than embedding the data inside an element like table.

For example, consider you need to display your data as:

```
ColumnHeader1 ColumnHeader2
DetailCell11  DetailCell12
DetailCell21  DetailCell22
DetailCell31  DetailCell32
```

Basic logic behind pagination is, Excel puts a page break at the end of a page and re-prints the column headers in the first line of the next page.

If we display this data as it is in the detail band itself then Excel pagination doesn't work as expected because Excel doesn't understand where to put a page break and re-print column headers.

Try to embed the data inside a table then pagination will surely work as expected.